# Unexpected Results in MS Graph Skype Endpoint

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

**SfbActivity (Detail, period D7)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',period='D7')/content
```

[image: SFBActivity]

This returns a user with a **Last Activity Date** and **Conference Organized Date** of 12th June, however running the endpoint for that date:

**SfbActivity (Detail, date 2016-06-12)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',date='2017-06-12')/content
```

Returns nothing. I did however manage to find this user on the 9th:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/SfbActivity(view='Detail',date='2017-06-09')/content
```

[image: SFBActivity]

But they have completely different stats - the **Last Activity Date** and **Conference Organized Date** have both changed from the 12th to the 9th.

User details have been redacted from the images, but it is definitely the same UPN. Also, this is the ONLY user to return on the 9th, and NOTHING is returned for the 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th (today is the 16th). This environment has definitely been seeing activity for all of those days.

**Questions**

1. Why are the Last Activity Dates different, depending on the type of call (period vs date).
2. When using the 'date' parameter, I would expect to see every user who has made an activity on that date. What is this actually doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. The Last Activity Date is consistent in both latest period and date reports. Report of date T is generated with data prior to T (inclusive), so the Last Activity Date will not be greater than T, and this is what you see in the report of 9th June.
2. We have fixed a bug for it. Now, all the daily active users are included in the user grid and exported file.